# MSVS 2015, C++, Calling constructor with arguments causes error

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am facing the following problem on MS Visual Studio 2015.

I have a `Hotel` class with an overloaded constructor that takes a string parameter.
When i try to create an object that uses the overloaded and not the default constructor, compiler faces the following error :

`Error  C2664   'std::Hotel::Hotel(const std::Hotel &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [7]' to 'const std::Hotel &'`

Hotel.h

```
namespace std {
    class Hotel {
    public:
        string hotelName;                       // Hotel's name.

        Hotel();            // Default constructor.
        Hotel(string);      // Overloaded constructor.
        ~Hotel();           // Default destructor.
    };

}
```

Hotel.cpp

```
namespace std {

    Hotel::Hotel() { // // Default constructor.
    }

    Hotel::Hotel(string name) { // // Overloaded constructor.
        hotelName = name;
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main() {
    Hotel Palace("Palace");
}
```

Over the search i did, i saw that MSVS uses two approaches for strings. And a solution for a similar problem i found was to cast `"Palace"` into `Hotel Palace(_T("Palace"));`

The same thing happens when i try to create an object from an overloaded constructor that has a type other than string as an argument.

Is this something that has to do explicitly with MSVS, or am i doing something wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should not place your own classes into `namespace std`

Comment: Why are you using std namespace?  Do you need to use a namespace at all?

Comment: There is plenty of other code that i need std namespace tag...You believe that's the problem?

Comment: Just use `using` statements like `using std::string;`.

Comment: Or `using namespace std` but this is not recommended

Comment: I [cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a8b9ba5a30a5f46) with GCC.

Comment: I think OP is not showing all of the Hotel methods.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on VS2017 and I doubt the provided code causes this compile-time error (since the constructor the compiler is complaining about does not exist in the code)

Comment: @zett42 I myself told that all not methods are included. Why would you need the methods when constructor can't be 'called'.

Comment: The compiler is trying to use `Hotel(const std::Hotel &)`, which you hadn't included in your example. This is probably happend because you are not using `explicit` keyword, so the compiler first tries to convert "Palace" string to Hotel instance, then call the constructor with `Hotel &` as the argument. But it couldn't convert `const char` to `Hotel`.

Comment: @UnholySheep http://i.imgur.com/W9LPFX4.jpg

Comment: Try to change `Hotel(string)` to `Hotel(const string&)`. You could also add another constructor: `Hotel(const char*)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems in your code that could lead to this error.

First, don't use `namespace std {...}`. Use

```
using std::string
using std::cout
```

instead. You can also use `using namespace std`, but this is not recommended. `Hotel(std::string)` is also fine.

Second, you should use `explicit` modifier in constructors:

```
explicit Hotel(string);
```

This would prevent some unexpected conversion errors.

You should also use `Hotel(const string&)` instead of `Hotel(string)`. This will prevent unwanted temporary copy of an argument.